# R paste function error

Tags: r, paste

I trying to produce this output character string

`CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS("7 - Past Medical/Surgical History")(PRECISE FORM OF "DM", PRECISE FORM OF "DM2", "diabetes")') <> 0`

using the paste function as below

```
paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS("7 - Past Medical/Surgical History")(PRECISE FORM OF "DM", PRECISE FORM OF "DM2", "diabetes")') <> 0")
```

I am getting an error

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS("7"
```

Not sure what I am missing here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: quotes need to be escaped inside other quotes, so replace the `"` with `\"` in your string

Comment: @bunk not sure I follow, I tried `paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS( \ "7 - Past Medical/Surgical History")(PRECISE FORM OF "DM", PRECISE FORM OF "DM2", "diabetes")') <> 0")` , now its showing me `Error: unexpected symbol in "paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History")(PRECISE FORM"`

Comment: `paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\")(PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0")` outputs
`[1] "CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\")(PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0"`

Comment: i.e. replace all instances of `"` with `\"`

Comment: @xxfelixxx , ah, that did it but that changed my output now, I am seeing few \    `"CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\")(PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0"`....I dont need those \

Comment: Yes, it is just a matter of display. Try `out <- paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\")(PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0"); cat(out,'\n')`.

Comment: @Pascal, oooh I am passing this output from paste function into a query ...`dbGetQuery(connect_JDCB, paste("....`, i wont be able to cat to get rid of the extra \

Comment: And? It didn't work or you didn't try? I didn't tell to use `cat()`. I just show you that what you see doesn't exist.

Comment: `noquote(paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\")(PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0"))`

Comment: @Pascal, i agree with you

Comment: @xxfelixxx, that worked perfect,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape all double-quotes `"` as `\"` and use `noquote`:

```
> txt = noquote(paste("CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS(\"7 - Past Medical/Surgical History\") (PRECISE FORM OF \"DM\", PRECISE FORM OF \"DM2\", \"diabetes\")') <> 0"))
> txt
[1] CONTAINS(ORIG_DOC,'SECTIONS("7 - Past Medical/Surgical History") (PRECISE FORM OF "DM", PRECISE FORM OF "DM2", "diabetes")') <> 0
>
```