# Avoid R function paste generating backslash for quotes

Tags: r, quotes, paste

I am trying to get two strings that contain quotations ("") combined as a character/string vector or with R function paste so I can plug the result in the argument x of writeFormula in [openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) package.

An example is like this

```
paste('HYPERLINK("file)',':///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B',sep="")
```

and I hope that it should produce the result like this

```
HYPERLINK("file:///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B
```

but it actually produces the result with a backslash in front of the ":

```
[1] "HYPERLINK(\"file):///\"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL(\"filename\",B"
```

I have searched for many potential solutions like replace paste with cat or [add noquote function in front of paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643848/r-paste-function-error) but the output is not a character vector.  Functions like toString or as.character could convert these results to strings but the backslash comes back as well.

Really appreciate any helps with this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no slash. \" is just " with an escape character in front of it. Try `cat(paste(...))`

Comment: Hi thelatemail, thanks for the answer. I had tried that before, but as I said, function cat and noquote cannot produce a character/string vector.

Comment: There isn't a slash in the string. When R print's the value to the screen, it adds it. Your paste is working just fine. Use `cat()` instead of the default print to see that, not instead of the paste: `cat(paste('HYPERLINK("file)',':///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B',sep=""))`. But the `cat()` is only for printing to the screen. The result from paste is what you want. Check out [this FAQ](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_88.html)

Comment: Please re-read the postings you found. You clearly did not read them with sufficient care. `grep("\\\\", "\'")` will return FALSE. So ... NO SLASH.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are no backslashes in `p`.  The backslashes you see are just how R displays a quote (so that you know that the quote is part of the string and not the ending delimiter) but are not in the string itself.

```
p <- paste0('HYPERLINK("file)', ':///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B')
p
## [1] "HYPERLINK(\"file):///\"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL(\"filename\",B"

# no backslashes are found in p
grepl("\\", p, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] FALSE
```

`noquote(p)`, `cat(p, "\n")` or `writeLines(p)` can be used to display the string without the backslash escapes:

```
noquote(p)
## [1] HYPERLINK("file):///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B

cat(p, "\n")
## HYPERLINK("file):///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B 

writeLines(p)
## HYPERLINK("file):///"&path!$C$1&TRIM(MID(CELL("filename",B
```

One can see the individual characters separated by spaces like this. We  see that there are no backslashes:

```
do.call(cat, c(strsplit(p, ""), "\n"))
## H Y P E R L I N K ( " f i l e ) : / / / " & p a t h ! $ C $ 1 & T R I M ( M I D ( C E L L ( " f i l e n a m e " , B
```

As another example here `p2` contains one double quote and has a single character in it, not 2:

```
p2 <- '"'
p2
## [1] "\""

nchar(p2)
## [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. There is indeed no slash when plugging the output of paste function in the argument I used. Also, thank MrFlick,  thelatemail, and 42  for your short answers.