# Equivalent function to excel's replace

Tags: r, regex, replace, quotation-marks

I would like to add quotation marks to hundreds of words (surrounded by blank spaces) and separate them by a comma. Preferably, by using only one or a few functions to avoid a manual replacement due to temporal expenditure.

Exemplary Problem:

```
words <- c("Paris Milan Berlin")
```

Output should be: "Paris","Milan","Berlin"

I've already tried `gsub()` and `str_extract()`, however I did not get the desirable outcome.

Comment: Hi, now that I read the answers, I think it is not clear whether you would like to have a character **vector** (with three elements in this case) or a single scalar string with the text `"Paris","Milan","Berlin"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gsub` to place `"` around words and place `,` between them.

```
x <- gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ",", gsub('(\\b[[:alnum:]]+\\b)', '"\\1"', words))
x
#[1] "\"Paris\",\"Milan\",\"Berlin\""

noquote(x)
#"Paris","Milan","Berlin"
```

Or event shorter as suggested in the comments by @zx8754

```
paste0('"', gsub(' ', '","',  words), '"')
```

Comment: Maybe? `gsub(' ','","', words, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: @zx8754 Oh yes, that's much shorter! Thanks. But the leading and trailing `"` is missing. I add them with `paste`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That works but how can I avoid these back slashes in the outcome?

Comment: @Maria26 The backslashes are just how R displays a quote. You can use `noquote`, `cat` or `writeLines` to to display the string without the backslash escapes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45362944/10488504

Answer (score 2):

With base R (given that you always want to split on a space) you can do as simple as

```
unlist(strsplit(words, split = " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be several ways. This is one of them:

```
library(tokenizers)
words <- c("Paris Milan Berlin")
tokenize_words(words, simplify =TRUE)
```

```
> tokenize_words(words, simplify =TRUE)
[1] "paris"  "milan"  "berlin"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the method of using `strsplit` (mentioned by [@Valeri Voev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139056/12158757)), another way is to use `regmatches()` and `gregexpr`, i.e.,

```
regmatches(words,gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]+",words))[[1]]
```

which gives

```
> regmatches(words,gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]+",words))[[1]]
[1] "Paris"  "Milan"  "Berlin"
```

To make a string output, the complete code is shown as below:

```
words <- c("Paris Milan Berlin")

r <- regmatches(words,gregexpr("[[:alnum:]]+",words))[[1]]

res1 <- toString(sapply(r, function(v) paste0('"',v,'"')))
# > res1
# [1] "\"Paris\", \"Milan\", \"Berlin\""

res2 <- toString(sapply(r, function(v) paste0("'",v,"'")))
# > res2
# [1] "'Paris', 'Milan', 'Berlin'"
```

Comment: That looks great! However, there are also words with numbers such as "Paris01" or "Milan04".
If I use your functions, the numbers disappear. I just get "Paris","Milan" instead of "Paris01", "Milan04".
Do you have an idea? :)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Maria26 Then you can try `[[:alnum:]]`, please see my updates

Comment: Great! It works but the commas are missing between the words please see the following:    [1] "Paris","Milan","Berlin"

Comment: @Maria26 do you want `'"Paris", "Milan" ,"Berlin"'` or `'"Paris, Milan, Berlin"'` with quotations in the string?

Comment: The first one :)

Comment: @Maria26 I added outputs with single and double quotations, you can choose either one according to your request